# PHP: preg_replace() to get "parent" component of NameSpace

Tags: php, regex

How can I use the [preg_replace()](http://php.net/preg_replace) replace function to only return the parent "component" of a PHP NameSpace?

Basically:

Input: `\Base\Ent\User`; Desired Output: `Ent`

I've been doing this using `substr()` but I want to convert it to regex.
Note: Can this be done without `preg_match_all()`?

Right now, I also have a code to get all parent components:

```
$s = '\\Base\\Ent\\User';
print preg_replace('~\\\\[^\\\\]*$~', '', $s);
//=> \Base\Ent
```

But I only want to return `Ent`.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not `explode('\\', $nameSpace);`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Explode is slow, I had my issues before with it, even my current solution based on `substr()` goes faster, but I would like do it regex-based. Thank you!

Comment: Is this for an autoloader?

Comment: @WesleyMurch nop, it's for a personal ORM-like thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rocket Hazmat says, `explode` is almost certainly going to be better here than a regex. I would be surprised if it's actually slower than a regex.

But, since you asked, here's a regex solution:

```
$path = '\Base\Ent\User';
$search = preg_match('~([^\\\\]+)\\\\[^\\\\]+$~', $path, $matches);
if($search) {
    $parent = $matches[1];
}
else {
    $parent = ''; // handles the case where the path is just, e.g., "User"
}
echo $parent; // echos Ent
```

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe `preg_match` might be a better choice for this.

```
$s = '\\Base\\Ent\\User';
$m = [];
print preg_match('/([^\\\\]*)\\\\[^\\\\]*$/', $s, $m);
print $m[1];
```

If you read the regular expression backwards, from the $, it says to match many things that aren't backslashes, then a backslash, then many things that aren't backslashes, and save that match for later (in `$m`).

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$path = '\Base\Ent\User';
$section = substr(strrchr(substr(strrchr($path, "\\"), 1), "\\"), 1);
```

Or

```
$path = '\Base\Ent\User';
$section = strstr(substr($path, strpos($path, "\\", 1)), "\\", true);
```